# htaccess forward slash goes folder deep

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this simple redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^tags/([^\.]+)/?$ home.php?search=$1    [L]
```

So if a url looks like

```
  http://example.org/path/to/folder/tags/exampleTag
```

It is redirected to

http://example.org.com/path/to/folder/home.php?search=exampleTag

It works, it redirects to home.php, but the problem is things and images on home.php. Apparently, the path when loading the images turns to 
         http://example.org/path/to/folder/tags/imgs/img.jpg

Instead of:
     http://example.org/path/to/folder/imgs/img.jpg

I.e, during redirection, the home.php loads things like it is in the tags folder and because they are not, the images do not get loaded.

How can I solve this?

On home.php I am using html to load images like this:

Both the .htaccess, home.php and the imgs folder are on the same folder

Comment: just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/path/to/folder/" />
```

so that all of your relative paths use the correct URI base.